# how to convert string to float value

Tags: python, offset, maya

I have this script where I'd like to copy animation based on user selection and paste back with offset. For the offset I'd like to use the input value from user but I get error in string to float, can someone help me to fix this ?
Thanks in advance

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Get the first selection
sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]

# Get the animation curves from the first selection
animCurves = cmds.listConnections(sel, type='animCurve')

# Get the time range of the animation curves
startTime = cmds.findKeyframe(animCurves[0], which='first')
endTime = cmds.findKeyframe(animCurves[0], which='last')

# Get the offset value from user input
offset = float(cmds.promptDialog(title='Offset', message='Enter offset value:', button=['OK', 'Cancel'], defaultButton='OK', cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel'))

# Loop through all other selections and paste animation with offset
for obj in cmds.ls(sl=True)[1:]:
    cmds.copyKey(sel, time=(startTime, endTime))
    cmds.pasteKey(obj, time=(startTime + offset, endTime + offset))
```

Comment: What's the error message and have you checked the value of `cmds.promptDialog(title='Offset', message='Enter offset value:', button=['OK', 'Cancel'], defaultButton='OK', cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')`?

Answer (score 1):

`maya.cmds.promptDialog` [does not return](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2023/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/promptDialog.html) the text the user typed, or at least, not the first time you call it:

> Return value
>
> *string*  Indicates how the dialog was dismissed. If a button is pressed then the label of the button is returned. If the dialog is closed then the value for the flag ds/dismissString is returned.
>
> In query mode, return type is based on queried flag.

The first time you call it, it returns either the label of the button the user clicked, or the value of the dismissString flag (`'Cancel'` in this case) if the user closed the prompt without clicking one of the labeled buttons.

If you call it again with `query=True` and `text=True`, *then* it returns the user's text:

```
closed_how = cmds.promptDialog(title='Offset', message='Enter offset value:', button=['OK', 'Cancel'], defaultButton='OK', cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')

if closed_how == 'OK':
    try:
        offset = float(cmds.promptDialog(query=True, text=True))
    except ValueError:
        # User entered invalid text. Do something about that.
```

Comment: the error I get is this:

# Error: ValueError: file <maya console> line 14: could not convert string to float: 'OK'